# Adjusted R-squared for tree-based models

Tags: regression, cart, r-squared

How can I use an evaluation metric like adjusted R-squared to evaluate tree-based models? It's not clear to me, since adjusted R-squared accounts for the number of predictors included in a given model, just how large *k* should be. Does this metric apply to tree-based models? If so, do I use, for the number of predictors, simply the number of columns in my input matrix? Or do I have to account for the number of splits/depth of the trees? Is there a better metric for evaluating the performance of continuous-regression tree-based models?

Comment: For tree models, one would typically estimate the predicted / out of sample R-Squared instead. Is there a particular reason that you don't want to use that one?